# How to list inheritance in protobuf when child classes are not in same assembly

Tags: c#, wcf, protobuf-net

In our application, we have the model(to be transfered over WCF with protobuf) in different packages, the "common" project is referenced by almost all the childs projects. In the childs projects we find all the classes specifics to some certains business area.

All the DLL are not shipped, depending on what feature the customer baught.

I know that one way of specifying the possibles childs classes is like:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(100, typeof(Derived))]
[ProtoInclude(101, typeof(Derive2))]
public class Base { 
    [ProtoMember(Order=1)]
    int Old; 
}
```

But in my case, I cannot reference the projects that contains `Derived` and `Derived2` classes(it would cause a cyclic reference, and even more important, it's weird that the parent has to know all its child).

With the default `DataContractSerializer` it was possible to specify a way to find which type of class we are using, is there a way to achieve this? Or I just cannot use protobuf with my constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it's weird that the parent has to know all its child.

No, that's actually normal; see also `[XmlInclude]` and `[KnownType]`, which work the same way

However, to avoid the circular reference issue with `typeof`, you can use the *assembly qualified name* as a string. To get the assembly qualified name, look at what `typeof(Foo).AssemblyQualifiedName` writes, then:

```
[ProtoInclude(100, "your assembly qualified name here")]
[ProtoInclude(101, "another assembly qualified name here")]
```

Another option is to configure everytime at runtime with `RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(RootType)].AddSubType(...)` - but: you still need to be able to configure it reliably with reliable integers.

Comment: Well, I keep my opinion that the object oriented approach is the opposite, and you can use a DataContractResolver at runtime instead of the KnownType. About the integers, one sub-question: They should be unique accros SubTypes and ProtoMembers? Also, between a parent class and its childs, should those number be unique or is there some mechanism to ensure that ID of the child are offset from the one of the parent?

Comment: @J4N no, they (members + includes) only need to be unique within an individual parent